# How do I draw a window on screen using GJS in a gnome extension

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs, clutter

I'm trying to create a GNOME Shell extension and draw a window on the screen using GJS. I have referred to the [gjs guide](https://gjs.guide/extensions/), the [official API documentation](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/), and the [gnome shell js source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/tree/main/js).

However, I don't understand how to draw a window because I'm not sure what the API methods return. Here is the code I've written so far for the stage:

```js
var stage = new Clutter.Actor(
{
   name: "fancygnome-stage",
   opacity: 100,
   width: 1000,
   height: 1000,
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
});
```

I'm not sure where to use this stage and how to proceed from here. I expect to have a method to put the stage somewhere and then draw on it. I've been stuck on this for 8 hours, and I would appreciate any help or guidance on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!